# How can I use in java the filtering function of the play framework 2 JsMessages plugin?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I use in java the filtering function of the play framework 2 JsMessages plugin ?
You can find the plugin code and documentation at [julienrf/play-jsmessages](https://github.com/julienrf/play-jsmessages)

I have read the scala example :

```
val messages = JsMessages.filtering(_.startsWith("error."))
```

I'm guessing the java version should be like :

```
final static jsmessages.JsMessages messages = JsMessages.filtering(play.Play.application(),/*a nice filter go there*/);
```

The java example should be update at the section corresponding to the generation of the jsMessage object but I could'nt guess how to pass a correct filter function. Here is the java example : [java sample code](https://github.com/julienrf/play-jsmessages/blob/master/sample-java/app/controllers/Application.java).

Here is the jsMessages part of my code. In commentary you got the correct implementation without filtering:

```
//final static jsmessages.JsMessages messages = JsMessages.create(play.Play.application());
final static jsmessages.JsMessages messages = JsMessages.filtering(play.Play.application(),---A play.libs.F.Function<String,Boolean>---);

public static Result jsMessages(String code) {
    return ok(messages.generate("Messages", Lang.forCode(code))).as("application/javascript");
}
```

So my problem is to create a play.libs Interface F.Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the java code for an implementation of filtering in jsMessages plugin:

```
final static F.Function<String, Boolean> filter = new F.Function<String, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(String key) {
        try {
            return key.startsWith("js.");
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
final static jsmessages.JsMessages messages = JsMessages.filtering( play.Play.application(),filter);
```

Just start crying by looking at the scala version of it :

```
val messages = JsMessages.filtering(_.startsWith("error."))
```